# How to remove app settings menu in settings screen - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app, I haven't used anything related to location finding or GPS. Initially there is no app settings. If I turn off the "Location services" in "Settings->Privacy->Location services", app settings appears with value "Location services" - "never". If I turn on the location services in "Privacy", my app settings disappears.

Problem happens when I goto settings from my app using `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString`, it will take me to app settings only (if app settings is present).

How could I make the app settings not to come when location services is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check the current status of the location services, using CLAuthorizationStatus and make your code work accordingly.